# $f(x)= \left\{ \begin{array}{lcc} x^3 & x < -1 \\ -1 & x=-1\\ x^2 &x > -1\end{array}\right.$. Find if differentiable to the right or left of $-1$

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

> Let $f$ be the function defined by:
>
> $f(x)= \left\{ \begin{array}{lcc}
>               x^3  & x < -1 \\
>               \\ -1 & x=-1
>               \\
>               \\ x^2 &x > -1 
>               \\
>               \end{array}    \right.$
>
> Investigate whether if this function is differentiable at $-1$ and, if
>   not, find whether if it is differentiable to the right or to the left
>   of that point.

My issue with this problem is that I don't understand what

> find whether if it is differentiable to the right or to the left  of
>   that point.

means.

Starting with the first part of the exercise, as far as I know the requirements for a function to be differentiable at a point are:

1. there isn't a vertical tangent at the point
2. it is continuous at that point
3. no "sharp" turn at that point

And to figure this out analitically, I have to see if $\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h} = \lim_{h\rightarrow0^+}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h} = \lim_{h\rightarrow0^-}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h} $

Looking at the function, I can see that there is a sharp turn at -1, and thus is not differentiable at that point.

If I try to calculate this analitically:

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow -1} \frac{f(x)-f(-1)}{x+1} = ???$$

Because $f$ approaches -1 differently from the left and from the right then I don't really know this limit. Unless I use $f(-1) = -1$ directly?

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow -1} \frac{f(x)-f(-1)}{x+1} = \frac{-1+1}{-1+1} = \frac{0}{0}$$

Since this is an indetermination, I assume the function is not differentiable at this point.

Now onto the second part:

- $(x^3)'=3x^2$
- $(x^2)' =2x$

If $3(-1)^2 = 3$ and $2\cdot(-1) = -2$ are not indeterminations, does that mean that $f$ is differentiable both to the left and to the right? Well, not according to my book:

> It is not differentiable at $-1$; it is differentiable to the left and
>   not to the right: $f'(-1^-)=3$ and $f'(-1^+)=+\infty$

So to try this I decided to use the formula $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}$.

I used it first on $x^3$ and I got 3, no issue there. However, when I tried with $x^2$  I got $+\infty$. In fact, it diverges and when $h \rightarrow 0^-$ it is $-\infty$ and when $h \rightarrow 0^+$ it is $+\infty$

So, my questions are:

1. Did I do anything incorrectly?
2. Why, when calculating the derivative of $x^2$ at $x=-1$, I get $-2$ with one method and $+\infty$ with the other? Which one is correct and why?